# How to point your local project on http://localhost:8080 port by wamp server?

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp, hosting

I would like to point the local project folder to directly run on the localhost 8080 port. Please suggest me the ways to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to put wamp/www to be accessed as localhost:8080?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using

Answer (score 0):

Just go to httpd.conf file, for ex. under WAMP environment its situated at:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf
```

go to line no. 46 and edit **Listen 8080** to your requirement for ex.

```
Listen 8383
```

newer versions of WAMP uses these 2 lines:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8383  
Listen [::0]:8383
```

Next go to line no. 171 and edit ServerName localhost:8080 to your requirement for ex.

```
ServerName localhost:8383
```

Restart Apache and its done !!

Now, you can access with your URL:

**http://localhost:8383 or http://192.168.1.1:8383 or http://127.0.0.1:8383**

Hope it helps to people looking for solution here.

**Note:: If you use VirtualHosts then you also need to update them to use  instead of**

Answer (score 0):

WAMP Your Project links do not resolve to localhost [Fixed]

Go to the location where you installed your wamp
Normally its C:\wamp64\www\index.php 
Use a text Editor i.e Nopepad, Notepad++
And find & change this line(33) to

```
$suppress_localhost = ($wampConf['urlAddLocalhost'] == 'true' ? true : false);
```

Save your file Index.php and close it

Then go to the right wamp icon notification icon and click/Tap to put online 
DONE!